# Center Content - Then Left Align With Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Goal:** Have text centered on the screen but still aligned to the left using Bootstrap 4. It should work regardless of the length of the item.

```
                            List Item
                            Longer List Item
                            Longer List Item With Lots of Info
                            Short
```

Getting the items to be centered was simple but then getting them to align left has been difficult. Any advice?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col text-center">
<p> List Item </p> 
<p> Longer List Item </p> 
<p> Longer List Item With Lots of Info </p> 
<p> Short </p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an inner div with a dynamic or fixed width (percentage of outer container is a good choice)

```css
.inner {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col text-center">
  <div class="inner">
    <p> List Item </p>
    <p> Longer List Item </p>
    <p> Longer List Item With Lots of Info </p>
    <p> Short </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need your `.col` to be also a flex container (`d-flex`)and wrap the content into a single div, then center it (`justify-content-center`) . You can use the bootstrap classes for that.

example below :

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex col justify-content-center">
  <div>
    <p> List Item </p>
    <p> Longer List Item </p>
    <p> Longer List Item With Lots of Info </p>
    <p> Short </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex col ">
  <div class="mx-auto">
    <p> List Item </p>
    <p> Longer List Item </p>
    <p> Longer List Item With Lots of Info </p>
    <p> Short </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put a width on the container (it could be fixed pixel or percentage) and apply auto left and right margin.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 mx-auto">
            <p> List Item </p> 
            <p> Longer List Item </p> 
            <p> Longer List Item With Lots of Info </p> 
            <p> Short </p>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/f5caxky3/